# how to move div with the scrollbar in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an image div like this

```
<div class="bgCover">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="overlayBox" style="position: fixed; background-image: url(../images/header.jpg)"  >

    <div class="overlayContent">

        <a href="javascript:void()" class="closeLink">Close</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

I am using jQuery to open the box like this

```
function getScrollTop() {

    if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined' ) {
        // Most browsers
        return window.pageYOffset;
    }

    var d = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype

    if (d.clientHeight) {
        // IE in standards mode
        return d.scrollTop;
    }

    // IE in quirks mode
    return document.body.scrollTop;

} //end of getScrollTop()

function doOverlayOpen() {
    ...
    showOverlayBox();
}

function showOverlayBox() {

    var scroll = getScrollTop();
    var top;

    if (scroll <= 28) {
        top = "30";
    }
    else {         
      top = (scroll + 2) ;
    }

    // set the properties of the overlay box, the left and top positions
    $('.overlayBox').css({

        display:'block',
        position:'absolute',
        left:( $(window).width() - $('.overlayBox').width() )/2,          
        top:top

    });

    // set the window background for the overlay. i.e the body becomes darker
    $('.bgCover').css({

        display:'block',
        width: $(window).width(),
        height:$(window).height()

    });
}
```

This open the box with respect to the scroll bar. But the problem is once the overlayBox is open, and then i move the scroll bar, then this div remain at it's position. I want that if user move the scroll bar then this div also move up and down.

I think i need to adjust the top, left corener of the overlayBox div with the scrollbar top.. Need to define a function that checks if scrollbar moves then move the div accordingly. Do i need delegation here or...  How can i do it?

Here are the images, in image 2 you can see, if i move the scrollbar then my image div don't move

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple: use `position: fixed` instead. So change it to

```
function showOverlayBox() {

    var top;


    top = "30px";

    // set the properties of the overlay box, the left and top positions
    $('.overlayBox').css({

        display:'block',
        position:'fixed',
        left:( $(window).width() - $('.overlayBox').width() )/2,          
        top:top

    });

    // set the window background for the overlay. i.e the body becomes darker
    $('.bgCover').css({

        display:'block',
        width: $(window).width(),
        height:$(window).height()

    });
}
```

the other functions (getScrollTop and doOverlayhappen) you don't need anymore

Comment: I tried this `$('.overlayBox').css({
        display:'block',
        //position:'absolute',
        position: "fixed",
        left:( $(window).width() - $('.overlayBox').width() )/2,
        top:top
        
    });` But now overlayBox is not showing :(

Comment: Ah ok you have to change the sizes of top left and so on. Because it is fixed it has to be for example top:10px; left:20px; right:20px; bottom: 10px; otherwise it would be fixed but many pixels under the screen

Comment: I am waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much, but you said **Because it is fixed it has to be for example top:10px; left:20px; right:20px; bottom: 10px; otherwise it would be fixed but many pixels under the screen **. What do you mean by many pixels under the screen? when i am using getScrollTop() to get the top position then it is not working, but with your code it is working... Why? Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: If the position is set to fixed, all positioning values are relative to the browser window. So its not depending on how far you scrolled down or something. If top is set to 20px it means it is positioned 20px under the browsers address bar or the top of the browser window. Fixed is relative to the browser window, and absolute "relative" to the entire page. Maybe read this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: HHmm ok thanks:) i understood that fixed means follow the address bar, therefore no matter how i scroll up or down it will always follow the addressbar. But tell me one thing please, in case of absolute, my entire page is the browser, whole browser(including the addressbar portion or excluding the addressbar portion?). So when i was using absolute, then once my div has positioned top, left, it can't move now onwards. No matter what happen it will  remain at their location. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, on absolute it remains at its position. The absolute positioning does not include the address bar, but the entire html page, like if it has much content it would have a height of e.g. 10000px or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Position:fixed` and then you can move the content of the div background with the scrollbar.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey8zU/) for you.