# Jquery Fade In/Out Scroll Formula

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have images that fade in and out as you scroll down on the page. The issue I am having is that the opacity is changing as soon as you begin to scroll.

Here is the formula:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".tre").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 500);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $(".two").css("opacity", 0 + $(window).scrollTop() / 500);
    });
});
```

As I understand it, one image fades out when scrolled down 500 pixels and the other fades in at that point.

What I want to do is just start the opacity change later in the scroll. How do I start the opacity change at 500 pixels down, and then the change would occur from pixels 500-1000.

Thanks

EDIT

Not sure it'll even work with this code now, might need something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the fraction that scroll has moved through a range you could use a function like this:

```
function fraction_that_scroll_has_moved_through_range( start, end )
{
    if( start < 0 || end <= start )
        return 0;

    var range = end - start;
    var current_pos = $(window).scrollTop() - start;
    var fraction = current_pos / range;

    if( fraction < 0 )
        fraction = 0;
    else if( fraction > 1 )
        fraction = 1;

    return fraction;
}
```

and then in your example call it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var f = fraction_that_scroll_has_moved_through_range( 500, 1000 );
        $(".tre").css("opacity", 1 - f );
    });
});
```

Comment: Works great. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there an easy way to adapt this code to make a div be at certain positions based on the scroll range?

Comment: Hey Nel, This function could continue to be used just the way it is, I'd think. You just position your div at one location if the result is < 0, another if it's between 0 and 1, and a third if it's greater than 1. You'd need to modify the range to suit your needs, of course, or possibly make use of multiple checks since you might want one effect to fire between scroll positions 300 -> 600 while another goes from 400 -> 800. It depends what you're doing. (Also note that on StackOverflow question-askers sometimes "upvote" and "accept" answers if they like them. :-) ) Small updates above.

Comment: Thanks. I tried upvoting earlier and it wouldn't let me, but I clicked the check mark now. I dont understand your response. I want a div to start somewhere, and then move somewhere else as I scroll from 500-1000. I dont know what to change in the code. opacity to position?

Comment: Ah. I think I have a clearer picture but a lot depends on the specifics of what you want the user to see. Positioning elements is a totally different beast than just setting opacity. Uhm... oh here's an answer that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027041/how-to-move-div-with-the-scrollbar-in-jquery